# SQLlite update statement not updating...Am I missing something?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got another stumper. My update function held in my database helper class is completing but when I query the database I find the old data instead of the updated data.

Here is how I make a connection to the database in onResume (I use onPause to close out of services etc)

```
 NiDB = new NetInfoDatabase(this);
```

Here is how I call the update entry code:

```
NiDB.updateDevice(device);
```

Here is my database update code:

```
public int updateDevice(Devices device){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, device.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_IP, device.getIp());
    values.put(COLUMN_MAC, device.getMac()); //Device MAC
    values.put(COLUMN_SSID, device.getSSID()); //Device SSID
    System.out.println("in the db code deviceIP " + device.getIp());
    // updating row
    int i =  db.update(TABLE_DEVICES, values, COLUMN_ID+" = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(device.getId()) });

    db.close();

    return i;
}
```

I also have a helper class called Devices that holds all the data. I know that the information is getting set there correctly. I even know that my update code is executing and that the device I pass has the correct information just before the execution of the following lines:

```
int i =  db.update(TABLE_DEVICES, values, COLUMN_ID+" = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(device.getId()) });

    db.close();

    return i;
```

I am wondering what I am missing here. I update does also get called in the onResume if that makes a difference.

When I print out the ip from the device I am using to update my database I get the correct IP but when I call the row from the database I get the same old incorrect IP. What is missing? Do I need to commit the changes to the database? Do I need to not call update from the onResume? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

### Thank you.

As an added point on interest I also cannot delete from my database. The problem persist even through complete app shutdown and restarts.

Here is my delete code:

```
public void deleteDevice(Devices device){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_DEVICES, COLUMN_ID + "= ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(device.getId()) });
    db.close();
}
```

Again if this looks correct to you as it does to me perhaps there is something in the way that I am calling this.

```
    @Override
protected void onResume(){

    super.onResume();

    //check wifi connection. Then run scan. 
            if(!checkCon(this)){
                wifiCheck();
            }else{
                NiDB = new NetInfoDatabase(this);
                checkDbIps();
                upDateSpinner();
            }
}
```

Here is the snippet that matters from checkDBIps();

```
    device.setIp("0.0.0.0");

    NiDB.updateDevice(device);

    System.out.println("here is new device IP" + device.getIp());
    String dbIP = NiDB.getDevice(device.getId()).getIp();
    System.out.println("here is what is in the DB " + dbIP);
```

The print statements print out as follows:

```
here is the new device IP0.0.0.0
here is what is in the DB 10.0.0.29
```

The DB at this point should match the new device IP. Should it not?

Comment: `db.close()` itself commits the changes. your `updateDevice()` code also OK. are you fetching the updated db or just viewing the old pulled one.

Comment: I am issuing the get command to view the data. But I know that the database is not updating because there are other methods that use the data and are not getting the new updated data when they are accessing the database. Thanks for the sanity check that my update code is correct.

Comment: Hi SMR do you mean make another call like this after updating: NiDB = new NetInfoDatabase(this);

Comment: What is the data type of that ID column?

Comment: It is int. It should be ok as I don't expect the database to ever get above 10

Comment: I think I just fingured it out. I actually had to add a call back to the database to retrieve the device I wanted to update **getDevice(id)** then assign that to a local variable **Devices tmpDev** then update tempDev's ip address. Then Call **updateDevice(tmpDev)** This ensured that the database was actually updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your values object might be help you

```
String COLUMN_ID = "_id=" + Id;

db.update(TABLE_DEVICES, values , COLUMN_ID, null);
```

Comment: what value of i after fire query

Comment: 0 same as the device id

Comment: Yes. That is the correct device. It appears that everything is executing but when I close out of app and return it has not updated.

Answer (score 1):

I like to concatenate a string of the command and then execute the statement

Some thing like this

```
String cheese = "Update table..."
db.execSQL(cheese);
```

This does not give any response but it works well any where a response is not needed.

If you want to look at the database from a command line perspective in a more real time situation you can use the adb (android debug bridge) tool and cd into the directory of the app. Once there find the database and open it using the *SQLite* command with the database as the argument. You can use pure SQL statements there.

Comment: This is interesting. One thing I should mention is that I do not define the database in my folder I'm letting the database helper class define the database.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // this is where you define the database.  I use the database helper class in my project as well.  Once the database has been created it is made in your apps folder on the device.

Comment: *Its made in the folder of the app on the device.  "apps folder" should have been "app's folder".